# estimating uncertainties in fitted parameters using lsqcurvefit

Tags: statistics, matlab, curve-fitting, uncertainty

I am using `lsqcurvefit` to fit function like this a.*x.^b, it will give me a , b and `resnorm`. 
I am wondering how can I have uncertainty for a and b. Is it possible to use 'jacobian' like this ?

```
[x,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output,jacobian] = lsqcurvefit (...)
```

then I will have a array with two columns which I think it related to this fact I ahve two parameters for fitting! but i don't know how to interpret it or use them for estimating error for a and b.

Comment: What's wrong with `resnorm`? What do you mean by uncertainty mathematically? You have all the errors given back to you in the `residual` output, you could easily use those to get a standard error for example... what exactly are you looking for mathematically. Perhaps you want to perform a t-test to determine whether `a` and `b` are significantly different from 0?

Comment: I think residual shows error for y, not for parameters a and b, I want sigma for a, b which are obtained after fitting function ydata=a.*xdata.^b; or I can say a,b are x(1), x(2). I would like to have uncertainty or sigma for them not y, as far as I know resnorm=sum(y-ycalculated)^2 and residual is y-ycalculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like this is best achieved using function in the statistics toolbox. See http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-18QY1/?solution=1-18QY1 and this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/56734 for examples on how to get the standard deviation of the fitted parameters but only if you have access to Matlab's statistics toolbox.

If you don't have that toolbox then from the wikipedia article on [simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Confidence_intervals) you can find the standard error of the slope parameter using the formula:

[image]

Most of the numerator there is `resnorm` and the denominator is fairly trivial to find:

```
sum((X - mean(X)).^2)
```

Where `X` is a vector of all your input independent variables used to find the fit

So you could convert your fit to a linear fit by taking logs so use `Yln = log(Y)` and `Xln = log(X)` to get the new model:

```
Yln = b*ln(a) + b*Xln
```

And use the formulas for standard error of simple linear regression parameters.

Comment: I still didn't get how we can take advantage of jacobian? What's your idea about this link [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/51136)?

Comment: This link shows you how to find the co-variance matrix of the parameters but I'm not really sure how to get from that to the standard error of each parameter. Sorry. From here on out the rest of your question is maths, not programming. Maybe ask on a maths / stats forum?

Comment: I found answer of my question here, this is exactly what I wanted to calculate error for each parameter from residual and jacobian. http://comp.soft-sys.matlab.narkive.com/Jq6b64k7/errors-of-parameters-deduced-using-lsqcurvefit